# how to reload same page after change the select box option

Tags: javascript

how to reload same page after change the select box option.

I have to used some shopping cart framework.In this i need to update cart price when i changed product attributes ,

so i need to reload the same page when the select box is onchanged.

```
<tr><td>
  <select name="color" onchange="">
   <option value="red"> Red </option>
<option value="red"> Blue</option>
<option value="red"> Green</option>
<option value="red"> Pink</option>
</select>
</td></tr>
```

Comment: without reloading the whole page..i believe you should use AJAX for this

Comment: Are you using any javascript Framework ?

Answer (score 12):

You can try this:

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <select name="color" onchange="location.reload()">
      <option value="red">Red </option>
      <option value="blue">Blue</option>
      <option value="green">Green</option>
      <option value="pink">Pink</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What to do if I want to reload for only a few selections?

Answer (score 1):

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $('#name').change(function() {
            location.reload();
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#something').change(function() {
    location.reload();
});
```